# could not create a new user in openam after customize opendj attribute

Tags: ldap, openam

After I add a custom attribute to person in opendj, When I create a new user tom in openam, I get org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldapDJLADPv3Repo encoutered a LDAP exception.65

debug log as follows：
org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldapDJLADPv3Repo encouter a LDAP exception.65

```
  DJLDAPv3Repo:07/30/2014 03:17:24:189 CST: Thread[http-8020-2,5,main] 
  ERROR: Unable to add a new entry: tom attrMap: {givenname=[tom], objectclass=           [devicePrintProfilesContainer, person, sunIdentityServerLibertyPPService,    sunFederationManagerDataStore, inetorgperson, iPlanetPreferences, iplanet-am-auth-configuration-service, organizationalperson, sunFMSAML2NameIdentifier, inetuser, forgerock-am-dashboard-service, iplanet-am-managed-person, iplanet-am-user-service, sunAMAuthAccountLockout, packt-services-user-class, top], inetuserstatus=[Active], uid=[tom], userpassword=xxx..., sn=[tom], cn=[tom]} 
  org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConstraintViolationException: Object Class Violation:  Entity uid=tom,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com encouter LDAP Schema configuration requirements，Cause it contains an unknown objectclass sunAMAuthAccountLockout 
  at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:173     ) 
at  com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.setResultOrError(AbstractLDAPFutureR esultImpl.java:125) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPClientFilter$1.addResult(LDAPClientFilter.java:94) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPClientFilter$1.addResult(LDAPClientFilter.java:79) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPReader.decodeAddResult(LDAPReader.java:310) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPReader.decodeProtocolOp(LDAPReader.java:1149) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPReader.decode(LDAPReader.java:166) 
   at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPClientFilter.handleRead(LDAPClientFilter.java:499) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:837) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) 
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) 
   at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I add packt-services-user-class to the extended opendj, And I have no idea why sunAMAuthAccountLockout is in Entity

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding all missing objectclasses and attributes according to the log and embedded opends